# Updating existing Spotify playlist via API

Tags: spotify, asp.net-web-api

I am using Spotify's web API to create playlist for a user.
I ask for all scopes except streaming, so i can create, update and delete user's playlist.

I can create, and fill my playlist, but i can't find in documentation how to update it. I tried with `POST` and `PUT` requests, but response is always `404 not found`.

Here is the documentation for playlist's endpoints:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/playlist-endpoints/

I can't find information about update and delete, despite references to `PUT` and `DELETE` requests here:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#requests

How can I update an existing playlist?

Comment: Can you show the exact code that returns the `404` response?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/playlist-endpoints/, there are no available APIs for updating playlists at this time.

We're always improving the Web API though, so stay tuned to the Spotify developer site for updates.

Comment: OK thanks ! Have you got an idea of when update and delete request will be available ?